# pass value from child to parent with EventEmiiter and dynamic component angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

Hi i have dynamic form using dynamic component loader 
So i have parent looks like this

```
<div class="item-form-block-content">
    <div class="form-block">
       <ng-template pf-host></ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

And many child that pasts in ng-template. And i want to pass data from child to parent. Im using `EventEmitter`

For example, one of my child component

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="onValueChange(value)"/>
```

In controller

```
export class childComp implements OnInit {
@Output() someVar = new EventEmitter<any>();

onValueChange(val: any) {
    this.someVar.emit(val);
}}
```

So how can i pass my `someVar` to parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply register an event listener on the child component in your parent component's template, like so:

```
<child (someVar)="doSomething($event)"></child>
```

And then define the method `doSomething(value: any) {}` in your parent component to handle the emitted values.

## Edit

Looking more closely at your requirements, and taking inspiration from [this GitHub post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6656#issuecomment-220820856), it would be possible to do this by manually registering event listeners in the parent component:

```
class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChildren(ChildComponent)  
    List<ChildComponent> children;

    void onSomeValEvent() {
        console.log("Event received!");
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.children.forEach((ChildComponent child) {
            child.someVal.listen((_) => onSomeValEvent());
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you see my parent component? There is <child> inside ng-template. And there are a lot of childs, based on my data structure. Where should i register an event listener?

Comment: You must register the event listener on the component which is emitting the event (via the `@Output` variable). This may mean changing your structure if you need to respond to events coming from your children components.

Comment: You may want to look at this [GitHub Issue Comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6656#issuecomment-220820856) which may be useful to you. You just have to manually register event listeners in the parent component through some lifecycle method.

Comment: I can't change my structure because i have to use dynamic component loader, because i have form with components depending on data.

Comment: Then I would try the method from the link in my previous comment.

Comment: So in my parent component in ts file i have to write override one of the lifecycle methode, for example ngAfterViewInit and inside listen to my variable someVar? I'm using angular 6 and get errors with @override